# Why does the solution to pendulum problem with the geometric approach of Jacobi metric does not correspond to the solution with Lagrangian approach?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, metric-spaces, classical-mechanics

When we solve the pendulum problem with EL equation, we get to the differential equation $\ddot{q}+\frac{g}{l}\sin q=0$
but when I apply the substitution $t \rightarrow t\sqrt\frac{g}{l}$ and calculate Christoffel symbols of the Jacobi metric $g=(e-V)(mgl)$ to find the geodesic equation I get to $\Gamma_1^{11}=\frac{\sin q}{2(e-V)}$ and thus to the equation $\ddot{q}-\frac{\sin q}{2(e-V)}\dot{q}^2=0$. How can we show that both equations have the same curves as solutions, and how do we get the equation obtained through Jacobi metric approach to be the same as the lagrangian one?

Comment: The question if well posed, but it is more appropriate for https://math.stackexchange.com/ rather then MathOverflow.

Comment: This is very vague. What is $e$, $V$ and so on ? Also, which references are you using ?